# How to apply styles to the react component via css modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, webpack

Ive got a problem with applying styles to my React Components.
I generated template to my project via Yeoman. It created a lot of config files, not only webpack.config.js and because of that I'm a little bit confused. As Readme file of react-generator says it support out of the box some features without installing it: 
*Different supported style languages (sass, scss, less, stylus)
*Style transformations via PostCSS
According to this I show part of `cfg/default.js`

```js
'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src');
const dfltPort = 8000;
function getDefaultModules() {
  return {
    preLoaders: [{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: srcPath,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      }],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&indentedSyntax'
      },
      
      {
        test: /\.scss/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'
      },
      {
        test: /\.less/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!stylus-loader'
      },
```

I think this part is responsible for converting `.scss` files.

So in my `todosStyle.scss` file I've got this code:

```
      .todos {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;} 
  .input {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;}
  .button {
    width: 60px;
    margin: 5px; }
  .label {
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px; }
```

Base on this styling I want to style my component `Todos.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";

    import Todo from "./Layout/Todo.jsx";
    import TodoStore from "../../stores/TodoStore.jsx";
    import * as TodoActions from "../../actions/TodoActions.jsx";
    import styles from '../../styles/todosStyle.scss';

    export default class Todos extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.getAllTodos = this.getAllTodos.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
        };
      }

      getAllTodos(){
          this.setState({
          todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
        });
      }

      componentWillMount(){
        TodoStore.on('change', this.getAllTodos);
      }

      componentWillUnmount(){
        TodoStore.removeListener('change', this.getAllTodos);
      }

      createTodo(){
        if (this.refs.addTodo.value != ''){
          TodoActions.createTodo(this.refs.addTodo.value);
          this.refs.addTodo.value = '';
        }
      }

      deleteTodo(todo){
        TodoActions.deleteTodo(todo);
      }

      completeTodo(todo){
        TodoActions.completeTodo(todo);
      }

      render() {
        const {todos} = this.state;
        const TodoComponents = todos.map(todo =>{
          return <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} completeTodo={this.completeTodo.bind(this, todo)} deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo.bind(this, todo)}/>;
        });

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Todos</h1>
            <div class = {styles.input}>
              <label class= {styles.label}>Add new Todo</label>
              <input ref="addTodo"/> 
              <button class={styles.button} onClick = {this.createTodo.bind(this)}><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></button>
            </div>
            <ul class={styles.todos} class="row">{TodoComponents}</ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

but styling isn't applied, although I've imported `todosStyle.scss`

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, its good to add $ on your loader test properties eg. test: /.scss$/, to only match end of file i believe.

i havent seen this before "import styles from '../../styles/todosStyle.scss';"
this kind of says that you are exporting styles from your sass file, perhaps import * as style ... might work, but i haven't used this approach.

try this.
require ('../../styles/todosStyle.scss');
this will bundle your css with the javascript.
then just use the class as you normally would on your render function.

also note; if you would like to create a separate file for your css, you can do that with plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You're using css modules but you haven't turned them on in your Webpack config:

`loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'`

becomes

`loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules!postcss-loader'`

As per the css-loader readme https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#css-modules.